# Restoring database backup file gives access error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am running SQL server 2008 and trying to restore from a backup file.

Note: the backup file and folder and read/write access to "everyone". Running the command as "master"

Running

```
 RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM DISK = 'D:\path'
```

Gives the following error:

```
Msg 3201, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Cannot open backup device 'D:\path'. Operating system error 5(Access is denied.).
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
RESTORE FILELIST is terminating abnormally.
```

Thanks,
Bruce

Comment: You mean D:\path\filename.bak, don't you?  I found this syntax in an old post [here](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/window-on-windows/how-do-i-restore-a-sql-server-database-to-a-new-server/454) and more documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173778.aspx).  Alternatively, have you tried restoring through the GUI to see whether you can get access that way?

Answer (score 4):

You need to actually [specify the backup file in the path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173778.aspx).  It's not the file list in an NTFS directory, as it seems may be your understanding. It's the **file list of the database files in the backup file**.

What you should be doing is:

```
restore filelistonly
from disk = 'D:\path\backupfile.bak';
```

Answer (score 0):

Had this error when restoring from a mapped drive (Actually a drive that was mapped by VirtualBox)

Fixed by moving data to a 'real' local disk

Comment: In this case though, he just used the incorrect syntax, the original answer is more correct

Comment: Yes it is, but this is what people find when googling for answers